# How can I improve my tests using PageObject pattern?

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, appium, pageobjects

I think I already get the gist of the PageObject pattern but there are some parts of it that I didn't get.

So I was following this tutorial and now I have this Page class:

```java
public class SignUpPage extends AbstractPage {

    AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    public SignUpPage(AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    public void signUpAllFieldsEmpty() {
        signup_button.click();
    }

    public void signUpOnlyFirstName() {
        first_name_edittext.sendKeys("First name");
        hideKeyboard();
        signup_button.click();
    }


    @AndroidFindBy(id="signup_button")
    private MobileElement signup_button;

    @AndroidFindBy(id="first_name_edittext")
    private MobileElement first_name_edittext;

    @AndroidFindBy(id="last_name_edittext")
    private MobileElement last_name_edittext;

    @AndroidFindBy(id="signup_email_edittext")
    private MobileElement signup_email_edittext;

    @AndroidFindBy(id="signup_password_edittext")
    private MobileElement signup_password_edittext;

    @AndroidFindBy(id="confirm_password_edittext")
    private MobileElement confirm_password_edittext;

}
```

Then I have this Test class:

```java
public class Test_001_SignUp extends AbstractTest {

    public Test_001_SignUp() {}

    @Test
    public void signUp_allFieldsEmpty() {

        app.landingPage().goToSignUpPage();        
        app.signUpPage().signUpAllFieldsEmpty();

    }

    @Test
    public void signUp_onlyFirstName() {

        app.signUpPage().signUpOnlyFirstName();

    }

}
```

I am not sure if I am doing it right because it looks like the method in the test class becomes redundant if I create another @Test method that will be relevant to the test.

How could I improve this? Or am I doing something wrong with this test?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Page` class should be stupid - it simply controls the page.

```
public void signup() {
    signup_button.click();
}

public void enterFirstName(String firstName) {
    first_name_edittext.sendKeys(firstName);
}

public String getFirstName() {
   etc...
```

Your `Test` class has the logic of which of those methods to call for each test.

A few other points:

- You aren't asserting anything in your tests.  You should add a `getSuccessMessage` method, or `getPageTitle` to your page (or whatever happens on your page once the signup is complete - something for your test to check that it worked!).  Then your test can assert that text is present and correct.
- Some frameworks use `StepDef` classes in between the Test and the Pages too.

Comment: Is it a good practice to assert text fields instead of titles? Since I'm testing a native Android app.

Answer (score 0):

If all your test have the same start point you can do it in a set up method with `@Before` annotation and clean method with `@After` annotation. They will run before and after every test method and will perform the action necessary to bring the test to its starting point

```
public class Test_001_SignUp extends AbstractTest {

    public Test_001_SignUp() {}

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        app
            .landingPage()
            .goToSignUpPage();
    }

    @Test
    public void signUp_allFieldsEmpty() {
        app
            .signUpPage()
            .signUpAllFieldsEmpty();
    }

    @Test
    public void signUp_onlyFirstName() {
        app
            .signUpPage()
            .signUpOnlyFirstName();
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp() {
        // roll back to initial state 
    }
}
```

As a side note, lets take as example `signUp_allFieldsEmpty()` test. `goToSignUpPage()` should return `SignUpPage` instance, so you can chain the next step

```
@Test
public void signUp_allFieldsEmpty() {
    app
        .landingPage()
        .goToSignUpPage()        
        .signUpAllFieldsEmpty();
}
```